# How do I update my password in Google Drive Desktop after I have changed it?

Tags: google-drive

I have changed my Gmail/Google Apps password for safety reasons.

The desktop client of Google Drive cannot synchronize anymore.
If I log out and log in again, it might want to download again all the files.

How could I update my password in Google Drive desktop client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the following method:

1. Click on Google Drive Desktop icon and quit
2. Run Google Drive again
3. You have an exclamation mark in the icon indicating an error: click on the icon
4. Click on the error message and it will open a window to login again
5. Login with your new password and that's it!

Hope it can helps.